# Trying to match lines from an object

Tags: python, for-loop

I was given two files. File1 is a list of genes with all possible connections that scientists have found. Its format is as follows: column 1 is gene1, column 2 is gene2 and column 3 is the edge attribute. File2 is a tab delimited file of only the genes and their locus in a disease of interest.

[image: left is File1 and right is File2]

The idea is to take file 2 and iterate over file1 in order to find the genes that match in a line and export those lines to a new file in the same format as file1. My code is as follows:

```
# define which indicies of elements to remove
indices = [0, 1]

# reading tab delimited file1 and remove first two elements of each line
with open('Input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: # for each line in file1
        line = line.split('\t') # split line by tab
        line = [i for j, i in enumerate(line) if j not in indices] # remove elements at indices
        print(line)

# create keyword list from above
FA_genes = line

# match FA_genes to genes in file2 and export lines that match to new file
with open('FA_genes.txt', 'w') as f:
    with open('STRING1.txt', 'r') as g:
        for line in g: # for each line in file2
            if any(keyword in line for keyword in FA_genes): # if any keyword in line matches any keyword in FA_genes
                f.write(line) # write line to new file
```

The problem is that there are lines in the exported file of FA_genes.txt that do not match any of the genes in Input.txt (file1). How do I go about testing to make sure all lines in FA_genes.txt. only contain the genes in the input file?

I tried removing elements in file2 in order to only have the genes of interest. I then tried to iterate these genes over file1 in order to find a match and then exported those lines that matched into a new file. I should theoretically only have the lines with genes that match but I have lines in my exported file where neither gene matches a gene from file1.

Comment: It would help greatly if you update your post with a sample (preferably short) of file1 and file2 and the expected output. Also, a clearer description of the rule would be good.

Answer (score 0):

if I didn't misunderstand, the main issue in your code is that you are overwriting the FA_genes list at each iteration of the first for loop while reading the input file ('Input.txt'). This means that by the end of reading the 'Input.txt' file, FA_genes will only contain the genes from the last line of the file.

To solve this problem, you should create an empty set for FA_genes at the beginning of the code and then add genes from each line of 'Input.txt' to this set. Additionally, you should use a set instead of a list for FA_genes to ensure that there are no duplicates. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
# Create an empty set for FA_genes
FA_genes = set()

# Read tab-delimited file1 and add genes to the FA_genes set
with open('Input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        gene1, gene2, _ = line.strip().split('\t')
        FA_genes.add(gene1)
        FA_genes.add(gene2)

# Match FA_genes to genes in file2 and export matching lines to a new file
with open('FA_genes.txt', 'w') as f:
    with open('STRING1.txt', 'r') as g:
        for line in g:
            gene = line.strip().split('\t')[0]
            if gene in FA_genes:
                f.write(line)
```

With this code, you should only get the lines in the 'STRING1.txt' file that match one of the genes present in 'Input.txt'.
I hope this helps you

Comment: this isnt the current issue. The current issue is that I have genes that do not match that end up in the output file after I try to match genes from file2 in file1

Comment: you should carefully examine your comparison algorithm. Try to look carefully at these points: Check the Data Formatting, Data Processing, Examine the Lines of the Output File, Add Debug Output,